# What statistical test should I perform for the data who comes from more than one population?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I want to check the chosen property (for example volume, density etc.) between data of experiment 1 and experiment 2, whether the difference of property between the experiment is significant or not?

My experiment 1 consist of 4 samples and experiment 2 consist of 3 samples.

My data in each sample comes from spatial region and have following sizes:

Experiment 1

- sample 1:  (300x1)
- sample 2:  (250x1)
- sample 3:  (200x1)
- sample 4:  (350x1)

Experiment 2

- sample 1:  (800x1)
- sample 2:  (750x1)
- sample 3:  (650x1)

What method will be good to perform statistical test.

(1) Merging all the samples of experiment 1 and experiment 2 and then perform the statistics.

(2) Merging all the samples of experiment 1 and experiment 2, plotting their histogram and perform the test on histogram value.

(3) Making similar bin (binsize 10) for each sample, take averages over bin for the samples in each experiment and then perform the statistical test.

I tried Kolmogorov-Smirnov for method 1; Spearman's rank correlation coefficient and Chi-square test for method 2 and 3 but none of p-values looks promising. I suspect that data in each samples comes from more than one population (meaning spatially different population) and these population may not be normally distributed.

What will you suggest: (i) what is the good way to arrange the data; and (2) which statistical should be done for such data?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by the $\times 1.$ Is the number $1$ subject to variation? A nonparametric test (such as two-sample Wilcoxon) will not be able to declare a significant difference at the 5% level, unless you supposed (before the experiments were done) that  Expt 2 gives larger values than Expt 1.

Comment: Welcome to CV, user3704712. I suspect your question will get better responses, and be less likely to be closed for being too unclear if you can edit "whether the difference of property between the experiment is significant or not?" to make explicit *which difference(s)* you care about? (e.g., mean? variance? distribution? etc.)

Comment: @BruceET Sorry for the confusion. (300 x 1) means 300 rows in a column. Meaning length of data in sample 1 is 300. It is column vector.

Comment: @Alexis  Each element in each sample is an object, which has a property like mass, density, volume, surface area etc. I want to check whether volume of objects in each sample of experiment 1 is consistently different from volume of objects in each sample of experiment 2.

Comment: Suspected something like that. My answer responds to that.

Comment: @user3704712 "I want to check whether volume of objects in each sample of experiment 1 is consistently different from volume of objects in each sample of experiment 2" **Different *how*?**

Comment: Looking this over, you probably have differences but you need to not compare mean volumes but rather all $n$ volumes in each category. in each "sample" to achieve good significance of difference. It should be OK to lump the first four sets of volume data together and compare those with the lumped next three sets, since that is what you seem to want to test. You might try Mann-Whitney test if you do not have normal conditions and unpaired $t$-test if you have normal conditions.

Answer (score 1):

**Two-sample nonparametric Wilcoxon test.** The two-sample Wilcoxon rank sum test looks only at ranks (relative positions). It is true that all of the outcomes in one experiment are substantially greater than any of the outcomes in the other. However, there are only ${7 \choose 4}$ possible ways for the $3 + 4 = 7$ outcomes to be allocated to two groups, and two of those show complete separation. And $2/35 \approx 0.057 > 0.05.$

Using data as shown below, here are results from 2-sample Wilcoxon tests as implemented in R. First, the two-sided test
that the two groups are have different locations; second, the
one-sided test that group 2 has smaller values than group 2.

```
x1 = c(300, 250, 200, 350)
x2 = c(800, 750, 650)
wilcox.test (x1, x2)        # two-sided test

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x1 and x2
W = 0, p-value = 0.05714
alternative hypothesis: 
  true location shift is not equal to 0

wilcox.test(x1, x2, alt="l")

       Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x1 and x2
W = 0, p-value = 0.02857
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is less than 0
```

**Welch two-sample t test.** If you are willing to assume
that your data are nearly normal, then you could use a t test.
It is not feasible to test such small samples for normality, so the judgment whether to use a t test would have to be
judged primarily on the basis of previous experience with such data. Results of both two-sided and one-sided tests give highly significant results with P-values much smaller than 0.05. [Welch two-sample t tests do not assume that the population variances are the same.]

```
t.test(x1, x2)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -8.3874, df = 3.9593, p-value = 0.001156
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -610.6699 -305.9968
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 275.0000  733.3333 

t.test(x1, x2, alt="less")

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -8.3874, df = 3.9593, p-value = 0.0005779
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is less than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
     -Inf -341.4931
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 275.0000  733.3333
```

**Permutation test:** *Using difference of means as metric.*

If your data are
numeric in the sense that sample means are valid measures of centrality, then you could use a permutation test. This type
of test takes numerical values into account, but does not require normal data.

At each step the data are scrambled between two 'groups' and the difference in means is found. The P-value of the two-sided test is about $0.03 < 0.05.$

```
set.seed(822)
d.obs = mean(x1) - mean(x2)
x = c(x1,x2)
m = 10^5;  d.prm = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
  prm.x = sample(x)
  d.prm[i] = mean(prm.x[1:4]) - mean(prm.x[5:7])
  }
mean(abs(d.prm) >= abs(d.obs))
[1] 0.02871
```

A histogram of the simulated permutation distribution is shown below. The P-value is the probability below the vertical red line.

[image]

*Using the pooled t statistic as metric.*
It may seem more familiar to use the pooled t statistic
as the measure of difference in means between two groups.
That the t statistic does not have Student's t distribution with $\nu = n_1 + n_2 - 2$ degrees of freedom (for our data $\nu = 5,)$ does not imply it's a poor measure.

In the program below, we permute the
group labels instead of the data, but the effect is the same. Also the P-value of this permutation test turns out to be very similar to the P-value for the permutation test above.

```
x1 = c(300, 250, 200, 350);  x2 = c(800, 750, 650)
x = c(x1,x2); g = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
t.obs = t.test(x~g, var.eq=T)$stat
set.seed(2019)
t.prm = replicate(10^5,
  t.test(x~sample(g),var.eq=T)$stat)
mean(abs(t.prm) >= abs(t.obs))
[1] 0.0279
```

The density curve of $\mathsf{T}(\nu = 5)$ is superimposed on the histogram of the simulated permutation distribution. Obviously, the permutation
distribution is not a t distribution. Perhaps this
casts doubt on using a pooled 2-sample t test to
analyze these data. But the permutation distribution
does not assume normality, and gives a useful result.

[image]

---

*Ref:* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)#Permutation_tests) has a good explanation of permutation tests. Section 4 of [this paper](http://jse.amstat.org/v18n1/eudey.pdf) discusses two-sample permutation tests. Also, you can search this site for other examples of 'permutation tests'.